# Why has this answer been deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25000089/581205) has been deleted by @ThiefMaster and I'm assuming he knows what he's doing. The answer is surely not perfect, but close to, especially in cases when the accepted answer can't be used.

[image: Screenshot for <10k]

So I wonder if this was an oversight or if I'm missing something?

At the same time, I'd like to know what's the best action in such a case (just undelete)?

Comment: I'm going to throw in a random guess and say Thiefmaster acted on a flag based on the first version of that answer?

Comment: @Bart Quite possible given the timing. PS: Thank you for the screenshot!

Comment: Note that the answer was deleted over 2 years ago. It might take a while for ThiefMaster to recall exactly what he was thinking :)

Comment: Huh? He's had *over two years* to think about it :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely I've seen the original version of the answer when checking the flag, which was nothing but this line without any code:

> It isn't hard to use in this manner, just do something along the lines of this

Possibly I had opened the flag queue and then got distracted for a few minutes so I still saw the old version. Impossible to say after almost two years.

Comment: Come on, you don't keep detailed notes on every single action you take on a volunteer job :-)

Comment: Sure this can happen and surely will happen if you do it many times. No problem. I wanted to ask you if you'd undelete it, but on the second sight, I've changed my mind (`new V()` is a nonsense). It looks like the answer tries to solve a problem I was having (and lead me to what I needed), but not what's been asked. It's not really good. So forget it.

Comment: Perhaps flag the question for close? However suitable answer it is unlikely further comments or views will contribute further